# How can I get my joystick to work with Dark Souls?

Tags: controllers, dark-souls

I have Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition, and would like to use my joystick (Hori Flight Stick EX2) to work with the game.

Is this possible, and how might I do it?

(By default, left, right, and some of the buttons do do things in Dark Souls, as do the directional hats (but the hats just move the camera)). Left and right stick are like A and D run left and right, but forward and back stick do nothing. The key mapper in the game doesn't notice joystick buttons or movements, apparently.

Comment: Get a gamepad...

Comment: By default, most games nowadays (especially RPG's and similar genres) don't support joysticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purchase this program called http://www.xpadder.com it works with most controllers, and it worked for my friend when his controller wasn't working. Xpadder allows you to map keys to controller keys. So, even if the game doesn't have native controller support it doesn't make a difference.